# Can't seem to get Sprite to face left in sfml c++

Tags: c++, sprites, rotation, sfml

I am having some small issues getting my sprite character to flip around. Basically I have a character that can walk to the right.. I am looking to flip it so that it looks like it is walking left.  I haven't found a working solution at the moment so any help would be amazaing!

I am using:

SFML 2.1
C++

I have tried:

```
  guy.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(guy.getGlobalBounds().width, 0, guy.getGlobalBounds.width * -1, guy.getGlobalBounds.height));
```

Comment: Try setting its X scale to -1

Comment: I tried that by doing guy.setScale(-1.0f, 1) and it makes the sprite disapear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sf::IntRect` that you will use will be the same for both directions. What will need to be changed is the scale of the `sf::Sprite` variable.

You will simply need to do something similar to this:

```
// Assumes that the image side is 24x32 and it is the first frame of the sprite
sf::IntRect test(0,0,24,32);
playerSprite.setTextureRect(test);
if( walkingleft ){
    playerSprite.setScale(-1.0f,1.0f);  //flip the sprite
}
// draw sprite afterwards...
```

Is the code you tried on your question the exact code you tried out, because it looks incorrect?

guy.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(guy.getGlobalBounds().width, 0, **guy.getGlobalBounds.width** * -1, **guy.getGlobalBounds.height**));

They are suppose to be functions.